# How to find the id of the source link in a Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, methods, hyperlink, controller

I have a page with 2 links calling the same Spring controller.  Suppose they are both calling this method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/messages/list"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewMessageLogs(ModelMap model) 
{
    return "messageLogs";
}
```

Each link has a different id value.  I need this controller method to somehow be aware of the id of the link the user used to reach it.  How could I accomplish that?

Thanks!

Comment: Either use `@RequestParam` or use `@PathVariable`

Comment: while the post referenced above isn't exactly what i want (i'm using path variables all over my app) it does provide an alternative.  I was hoping not to modify the URL and that the controller could somehow have access to the name of the source link (through the BindingResult for example) but i was able to achieve what i wanted by changing the method annotation to @RequestMapping(value = {"/messages/list-{type}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET) and changing my links accordingly.  Thanks

Comment: that should be fine as it solves your problem?

Comment: it's a workaround.  I was hoping to achieve this without modifying the URL but indeed it solves my problem

Comment: Yeap workarounds always help